# How do i Query using mutiple strings in where statement in LINQ

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I'm wondering how and if I can query on multiple strings/ints easily doing something like this?

```
var test = from a in db.PlasserLans
from b in db.Ulans
where a.registeredNick == b.Username &&
a.Nick == {"Ayuris" , "Crey" , "DjMofasa" , "esel" , "Firaxa" , 
           "Kindleguy" , "Michigo" , "moiC" ,"Shibiz"}
orderby a.Nick
select new
{
    Nick = a.Nick,
    Username = b.Username,
    Email = b.UserEMail,
    RealName = b.UserRealname,
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create the list before the query, that would make it easier to understand. Also you can do a join instead of looping on both tables.

```
List<string> nickList=new List<string> {"Ayuris" , "Crey" , "DjMofasa" , "esel" , "Firaxa" , "Kindleguy" , "Michigo" , "moiC" ,"Shibiz"};

var test = from a in db.PlasserLans
           join b in db.Ulans
           on a.registeredNick equals b.Username
           where nickList.Contains(a.Nick)
           orderby a.Nick
           select new
                  {
                      Nick = a.Nick,
                      Username = b.Username,
                      Email = b.UserEMail,
                      RealName = b.UserRealname,
                  };
```

Answer (score 1):

In Linq-2-sql its just the other way around

```
 where .... &&
 {"Ayuris" , "Crey" , "DjMofasa"}.Contains(a.Nick)
```

This is by heart, not sure if the direct usage of {} works, but you need to checkout the .Contains() for linq-2-sql and it will work.

Comment: I had to make it a array first running it directly on the {} don't work. got it to work using your way indirectly